# Analogous notions of Motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to get some (naive) intuition about the theory of motives...I just know that the idea is to provide some explanation for the several cohomology theories that can be associated to an algebraic variety. So, my question would be:

Is there an analogous notion of motives for other geometric categories (e.g., $C^{\infty}$-smooth manifolds), or this just makes sense for algebraic varieties?

Comment: Daniel Dugger's book-in-progress "Navigating the motivic world", available on [his webpage](http://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/), discusses motives for the category of topological spaces (Chapter 9).